# mysql query limit theory,how to response the client

Tags: mysql

Could you please kindly teach me the theory of mysql query:
if my sql is:`select * from user where city='NewYork'`. then the mysql engine(server) will one said queries the table and one said responses the result(one by one)? or, after querying some size results and put then into a cache,then batch response to the client? and If I use a limit for instance limit 10,so I want to know whether the mysql queries all of the results out then response 10 results,or just query 10 results(not query all) and response to the client.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is a reasonable question all though the english is not great

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the server will execute the entire query before trying to return results. Also with a limit clause the server will stop processing the query once it knows that the limit criteria have been met. Note that just because a limit clause was used it does not mean that the server did not read every record in the table.

Comment: Thank you,but I think If the mysql execute the entire query then return result,if query a one million rows and 10K per row,then the total data has 10G,then the memory might crush. So I more believe there is a cursor or a cache.

Comment: When did I say the result was copied into RAM?

Comment: Oh,I understand,you mean that is stream?directly to network IO ?
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good discussion on the considerations of `LIMIT`.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: From the God's of mysql :-) amazing stuff those guys do